# Getting excerpts from sphinx with the php api

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm trying to get sphinx search to return excerpts of matched documents.  I'm using http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/trunk/api/sphinxapi.php to speak with the sphinx daemon.

At the moment I'm only getting back the following:

```
[matches] => Array
    (
        [28] => Array
            (
                [weight] => 2
                [attrs] => Array
                    (
                        [serialized_time] => 1252664548
                    )

            )
```

Does anyone have any examples of how to command sphinx to include excerpts as well as document id's, etc...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API document is on a wiki page, it may help you out.

http://www.sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs

Comment: Thanks for that.  Weird how it wasn't coming up in google.

Anyways, for anyone else with this problem: http://www.sphinxsearch.com/wiki/doku.php?id=php_api_docs#buildexcerpts_documents_index_words_options

Comment: The link in the answer is dead.  Here is the Sphinx documentation on building excerpts: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/api-func-buildexcerpts.html